# Gesture detectors malfunctions in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gesture

For my app  i am implementing `recyclerview` to display images in grid format.
`onlongPress` i need to delete multiple items.
`onclick` i need to display clicked image in a new activity.

so i used `SimpleOnGestureListener` for achieving it.

First i implemented `onLongPress` it worked fine.But it returned id as -1 if i longpress elsewhere in the recyclerview other than the image.I handled it by placing a condition `id !=-1`.
**question1:** is this correct way of doing or am i doing anything wrong?

Next after this i implemented `onSingleTapUp` for on click. when i do `onLongPress`, `onSingleTapUp` is also called. I handled it my placing a flag to indicate its long press.
Now if i do a single click on the image, `onSingleTapUp` is called multiple times incremently. for eg: if i press first time called 2 times.next time 6 and goes on incresing. 
**question2:** how to solve `onSingleTapUp` getting called on `onLongPress` and `onSingleTapUp` getting called multiple times?

**updated:**
`MainActivity`

`

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClicked(int position) {
    if (actionMode != null) {
        toggleSelection(position);
    }
}

private void toggleSelection(int position) {
    mAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
    int count = mAdapter.getSelectedItemCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        actionMode.finish();
    } else {
        actionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(count));
        actionMode.invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClicked(int position) {
    if (actionMode == null) {
        actionMode = startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
    }

    toggleSelection(position);

    return true;
}
private class ActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final String TAG = ActionModeCallback.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate (R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:
                // TODO: actually remove items
                Log.d(TAG, "Delete called");
                List<Integer> selectedItemPositions = mAdapter.getSelectedItems();
                int i;
                int currPos;
                for (i = (selectedItemPositions.size()) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    currPos = selectedItemPositions.get(i);
                    mAdapter.removeData(currPos,filePath);
                }
                getDirectoryFiles();
                setUpRecyclerView();
                mode.finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mAdapter.clearSelection();
        actionMode = null;

    }
}`
```

`Adapter`
`

```
   public class GridAdapter  extends SelectableAdapter<GridAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<images> mItems;
private ArrayList<String> filePath;
final Context mContext;

private ViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener;


public GridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> fileName, ArrayList<String> filePath, ViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener) {
    super();
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    this.filePath = filePath;
    mItems = new ArrayList<images>();
    this.mContext = context;
    for (int i = 0; i < fileName.size(); i++) {

        images img = new images();
        img.setName(fileName.get(i));
        img.setThumbnail(i);
        mItems.add(img);
    }
}

public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
   // View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v,clickListener,mContext,filePath);
    return viewHolder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    // Decode the filepath with BitmapFactory followed by the position
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {
        bmp = decodeFile(new File(filePath.get(i)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Picasso.with(mContext).load(new File(filePath.get(i))).into(viewHolder.imgThumbnail);
    // Set the decoded bitmap into ImageView
    viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmp);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

public void removeData(int currPos, ArrayList<String> filePath) {

    File f=new File(filePath.get(currPos));
    f.delete();
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
        View.OnLongClickListener {

    public ImageView imgThumbnail;

    private ClickListener listener;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> filePath;
    public int press_flag=0;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, ClickListener listener,Context context,ArrayList<String> filePath) {
        super(itemView);
        imgThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
        this.listener = listener;
        this.mContext=context;
        this.filePath=filePath;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
      //  Log.v("method","viewholder constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(press_flag==0) {
            Log.d("onclick", "Item clicked at position " + getPosition());
            int j = getPosition();
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, image_preview.class);
            i.putExtra("j", j);
            i.putExtra("filepath", filePath.get(j));
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onItemClicked(getPosition());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Onlongclick", "Item long-clicked at position " + getPosition());

        if (listener != null) {
            return listener.onItemLongClicked(getPosition());
        }
        return false;
    }


    public interface ClickListener {
        public void onItemClicked(int position);

        public boolean onItemLongClicked(int position);
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: Using a gesture detector for clicks and long clicks is overkill, and complicated to do this fine. You should use an `OnClickListener` and an `OnLongClickListener` on your `ViewHolder`. See here for example: http://enoent.fr/blog/2015/01/18/recyclerview-basics/#Respond.to.clicks.on.items

Comment: I was searching for this solution for a long time.Your solution seems good.I will give it a try.thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Kernald everything is working fine but a click followed by a long press of an item calls both onclick and toggle selection.

Comment: could you update your code?

Comment: That's weird, what do you mean by "a click followed by a long press"? A tap, release, then a new long tap? Or just one, long tap? I have almost the same logic code as you, the behavior is fine on my side…

Comment: i mean during multiple selection, every selection i.e a click followed by a long press(first item selection which triggers action bar) calls my onclick listner as well.

Comment: for eg:if i long press item 1 which triggers action bar. then in order to do multiple selection i click on item 2 to add to the list . the problem here is item 2 is added and also its listener for onclick is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98085/discussion-between-kernald-and-user305774).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is about the second problem OP encountered: after switching from a `SimpleOnGestureListener` to simple `OnClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener`, when clicking on an item, the preview activity (supposed to be shown when in normal mode) is shown even if the user is in selection mode.

---

You actually have two places called when an item is clicked. From the `ViewHolder` (in the adapter file):

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(press_flag==0) {
            Log.d("onclick", "Item clicked at position " + getPosition());
            int j = getPosition();
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, image_preview.class);
            i.putExtra("j", j);
            i.putExtra("filepath", filePath.get(j));
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onItemClicked(getPosition());
        }

    }
```

And from the listener, in this case, your `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onItemClicked(int position) {
    if (actionMode != null) {
        toggleSelection(position);
    }
}
```

So, what happens there? First, your `ViewHolder`'s listener method gets called. If `press_flag` equals 0 (which I guess is an attempt to fix your problem, and is always true), you start the preview activity. In any case. Then, you notify the `MainActivity`. This `MainActivity` is in charge of setting an item as selected or unselected, and knows about the current selection state.

You  have a simple fix here: move your preview starting code to the `MainActivity`. Your code becomes something like that:

`ViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onItemClicked(getPosition());
    }
}
```

`MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onItemClicked(int position) {
    // If we are already selecting something
    if (actionMode != null) {
        toggleSelection(position);
    } else { // Or if we're not
        Log.d("onclick", "Item clicked at position " + position);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, image_preview.class); // mContext is useless here as we already are in a Context
        i.putExtra("j", position);
        i.putExtra("filepath", mAdapter.getFilePath(position); // New method to create in the adapter
        startActivity(i); // Again, no need for an additional Context here
    }
}
```

`Adater`:
You need a new method to fetch the file path from the `MainActivity`, really simple. You may already have the information in the `MainActivity`…

```
public String getFilePath(int position) {
    return filePath.get(position); // You may need to check for position being valid (compare to 0 and filePath.size())
}
```

Comment: Its working...thanks Kernald! its a simple fix. You are lifesaver!! :D